# How do I root a Samsung Galaxy S4 SGH-I337?

Tags: rooting, samsung-galaxy-s-4, bootloader-lock

I have a Samsung Galaxy S4 SGH-I337 with a I337UCUAMF3 baseband. How do I either root it and unlock the bootloader or install a mod? Alternately, can I change it back to a previous baseband and unlock the bootloader?

Comment: As you correctly used the `rooting` tag, have you followed up to our [rooting index](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/1184/16575) via [its tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/rooting/info)? There you can find e.g.: [Galaxy S4 SCH-I545](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/49766/16575) and [Galaxy S4 Mini GT-I9195](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/54075/16575).

Comment: @Izzy It's SGH-I337, not SCH-I545. And definitely not a Mini ;)

Comment: Good you say so! Mind to [edit] your question and include that, before anyone gets the idea your question might be a duplicate to one of those? ;)