# How Can I Root My GS4 Without Bricking It Again

Tags: rooting, samsung-galaxy-s-4

So... I've rooted all of my devices in the past: tablets and phones and 2 months ago I tried rooting my Galaxy S4 and bricked it, even though I followed an XDA video on how to root.

I followed all of the steps exactly as instructed and still bricked my GS4.

So... Is there any way/video/method that can help me root my new GS4 without bricking it this time? Or should I just forget about it?

I have the T Mobile SGH-M919 I believe

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts! You might want to start with our [rooting tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/rooting/info), followed by our [rooting index](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/1184/16575): [Galaxy S4 SCH-I545](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/49766/16575) / [Galaxy S4 (Verizon, Android 4.3)](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/58823/16575) / [Galaxy S4 Mini](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/54074/16575)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot really root a bricked phone. However, assuming your phone is **not** currently bricked, there's a very straightforward [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ONzxfyTnWIY) by wwjoshdew that you can follow.